# Insert with no refresh with php and ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I was working on an asp project and i've now migrated to php. i used an ajax script to submit to database without refreshing the page in asp. Now i'm using that same ajax script in php but it fails to work. When i open the console in google chrome it shows no errors too but when i check the database i find no records submitted.

HTML AND AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script>


$(function(){
      $("#form1").submit(function() {
            $.post("insert.php", $(this).serialize(),function(data){
                  // I am done. The page returned by insert_db.php is now in data
            } )
            return false
      })
})

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="form1">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>firstname</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname"  id="fname"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lastname</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname"  id="lname"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
<table border="1">


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connect.php'); ?>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      
    include 'connections/connect.php';

                    $fname=$_POST['fname'] ;
                    $lname= $_POST['lname'] ;                   


         mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname) VALUES ('$fname','$lname')"); 


            }
?>
```

CONNECTION STRING

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_connect= "localhost";
$database_connect = "speedapp";
$username_connect= "root";
$password_connect= "user2";
$connect= mysql_pconnect($hostname_connect, $username_connect, $password_connect) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Comment: what error message said ?

Comment: If nothing is inserted then definitely `$_POST['submit']` is not set. Have you checked your `$_POST`? What values are there?

Comment: This is a typo Give name to your submit button like name="submit"

Comment: done that but still not working

Answer (score 1):

You have not selected the DATABASE.
Include the following in `connect.php`

```
$db = mysql_select_db($database_connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
      $("#form1").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent the form submission
            $.post("insert.php", $(this).serialize(),function(data){
                  // I am done. The page returned by insert_db.php is now in data
            } )

      });
});
```

Comment: still cannot submit to the database

Comment: then you have an error in your ajax call ..check in firebug console

Answer (score 0):

Make your js to prevent default action of submit :

```
$(function(){
  $("#form1").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default
        $.post("insert.php", $(this).serialize(),function(data){
              // I am done. The page returned by insert_db.php is now in data
        });
  });
});
```

and you have to add `name="submit"` to your input submit tag :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

And make your insertion safe :

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){      
   include 'connections/connect.php';
   $fname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
   $lname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);                   

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname) VALUES ('".$fname.",'".$lname."')"); 
}
?>
```

I suggest you to not use `mysql_*` anymore, because it was deprecated and will be removed soon in latest version of PHP

Answer (score 0):

`if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is looking for an input with a name of `submit`.

Update your button to the following...

`<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Check in your console to validate if data is passing to correct Url. Also you are not using this variable $database_connect anywhere in your code. You need to select the right DB.

Answer (score 0):

In Input type submit name is missing. Without it your code will not move further after  `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`